# Conflicting Javascript drop down and slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, slideshow

I am working on a website and am encountering some issues when it comes to some Javascript. I have a menu and a slideshow. These work independently, on their own pages, but when I put them together- all hell breaks loose. I have uploaded what I have so far but cannot figure out why the slideshow is breaking. Any help would be appreciated. I have looked into noconflict, and even some alternative slideshow's that don't use jquery, but that is a bust as well. Link below:

[test page](http://lmiah.site11.com/_site-dev-about/slidetestweb.html)

You can see, if you hover over the menu the intended effect occurs, however the slide show (I bordered them in black so you can see all 4 slides, does not work anymore.)

Edit: This is the error I am getting:

**$("div.slides > ul", $slideshow.context).cycle is not a function**

**[Break On This Error]**
**pause: true**

Comment: can you put this into a jsfiddle?  Will make it easier on the people trying to help

Comment: Why are you importing two jQuery libraries?  One in the head and one at the end of your body

Comment: I took out the top jquery library, still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you have jQuery.noConflict(); but you've then continued using $ to reference the jQuery Object.

Also, if you look in the source you are linking to http://lmiah.site11.com/_site-dev-about/js/jquery.hoverIntent.js which goes to a 404 page - this may be causing some issues.

Comment: Oh that was for an older menu I took out (hoverIntent.) Should I take out the noConflict() or change the references?

Comment: I would take out noConflict unless your using other libraries